# Adding <div> and classes to form in zf2

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

i want to add css class and division tag for each in this form. I am not getting how to do it. i can add class for label and input field as well but not getting how to add .

my form is like this

```
namespace Erp\Form;

use Zend\Form\Form as Form;

class LeadsForm extends Form {
    public function __construct($name = null){
        parent::__construct('leads');

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'id',
            'type' => 'Hidden',
        ));
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'companyName',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'attributes' => array(
                'class' => 'req'
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Company Name',

            ),
        ));
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'website',
            'type' => 'Text',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Website',
            ),
        ));
```

It displays like this (Source code)

```
    <form method="POST" name="leads" action="&#x2F;erp&#x2F;public&#x2F;leads&#x2F;add" id="leads">
<fieldset >
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="">
<label><span>Company Name</span>
<input type="text" name="companyName" class="req" value=""></label>
<label><span>Website</span>
<input type="text" name="website" value=""></label>
```

But i want this to be like this

```
<form method="POST" name="leads" action="&#x2F;erp&#x2F;public&#x2F;leads&#x2F;add" id="leads">

<input type="hidden" name="id" value="">

<div class="formSep">
<label class="req">Company Name</label>
<input type="text" name="companyName" class="req" value="">
</div>

<div class="formSep">
<label class="req">Website</label>
<input type="text" name="website" value="">
</div>
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 3):

I assume that your are using this code in order to render your form.

```
$form = $this->form;
$form->prepare();
echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
echo $this->formCollection($form);
echo $this->form()->closeTag();
```

While this works as expected, it's not that much flexible for cases like yours. So to render a form in your view file the way you want it, you must use [View Helpers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.view.helpers.html) and render every form input one by one.

```
 $form = $this->form;
 $form->prepare();
 echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
 echo $this->formHidden($form->get("id"));
 <div class="formSep">
     echo $this->formText($form->get("companyName"));
 </div>
 <div class="formSep">
     echo $this->formText($form->get("website"));
 </div>
 echo $this->form()->closeTag();
```